# How do we find out the google smart home action data server location?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-smart-home

I am trying to find out the google data server location for Smart Home actions.

Could someone pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on how you have your project configured in Google Cloud Console. You can [look up or change the default regions and zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/changing-default-zone-region#how_a_default_region_and_zone_affect_your_project) in your project's settings.